# Unable to display text over custom EditText With Modification in getEditableText()

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am setting up a custom EditText View in my native android app with the modifications in `getText()` and `getEditableText()`, I am performing encryption on plain text inside these methods, and facing issue in some device.
The issue is unable to display text over EditText View on some device if `getEditableText()` implemented inside class.

I have tried to return encrypted value, Null value, the static value from `getEditbaleText()`.
if I not implemented `getEditableText()` it will directly call to parent class method.

```
//ByDefault method 
@Override
    public Editable getEditableText() {
        return super.getEditableText();
    }
//Modified method 
//Encrypted Value
1)@Override
    public Editable getEditableText() {
        try {
            CharSequence encryptedText = super.getEditableText();
            if (encryptedText != null) {
                Context context = getContext();
                SecureSDKImpl_inner secureSDKImpl_inner = null;
                if (context != null) {
                    secureSDKImpl_inner = new SecureSDKImpl_inner(context);
                    if (secureSDKImpl_inner != null) {
                        encryptedText = secureSDKImpl_inner.EncryptText(encryptedText.toString());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, null);
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,"secureSDKImpl_inner is null");
                return null;
            }
            return new Editable.Factory().newEditable(encryptedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
//try to retun null
2)@Override
    public Editable getEditableText() {
     super.getEditableText();
     Editable editable=null;
        return editable;
    }
//try to return null
3) @Override
    public Editable getEditableText() {
        CharSequence encryptedText="";

        return new Editable.Factory().newEditable(encryptedText);

    }
```

On Some Device Unable to Type a single character on EditText. Mostly occurs with Gionee, MIUI, EMUI.

I am expecting either null or an encrypted value from
`getEditableText()`

Note- No issue with `getText()`